# try to make infinity scroll using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll

i try to make infinity scroll using angular js .my code

```
app.controller('cardCtrl', function ($scope, $http,$window,$location) {     
    var isNext = true;
    var next;
    $scope.init=function(authtoken,cityname){           
        $scope.authtoken=authtoken;
        $scope.cityname=cityname;   
        if(isNext) {
            next = '/api/v1/asasa?city='+$scope.cityname+'&auth='+$scope.authtoken;             
            isNext = false;
        }
        next = next.replace('localhost:8030','');
        $http({method: 'GET', url: next}).success(function(data) {              
            $scope.card = data.aggregations;                
            $scope.deal = data.deals; 
             next = data.next;                                  
        });             
    };
```

Now this infinity scroll working fine.I just face one problem How i store every api data in $scope.deal (every api same structure)

Comment: Have yu checked the ui-scroll?
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/scrollfix

Comment: Stop building what you are doing and use [ui-scroll](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils) it has the most fundamental feature "destroying elements as they become invisible and recreating them if they become visible again." - avoids creating watcher and make you app sluggish